# Using undefined constant in perl file not throwing any warning

Tags: perl

I have a module where I have few variables declared `hfs_const.pm`. I
am using this module in another Perl program.

I am also using few of the module's variables in another Perl file.

**Test case:** I remove one variable from the module which I am using in the Perl file through an object. Then I compile the Perl file.

I am using `use strict` and `use warnings`, but when I compile the Perl program it shows that everything is OK.

I believe it should have thrown an error for undeclared module variable.

Following is the module and Perl file

#### hfs_const.pm

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

package hfs_const;    # const definition file for hfs.
use Exporter 'import';

use strict;
use warnings;

#--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

use constant ENABLE_HFS     => 1;
use constant PROC_MOUNT_DIR => "/proc/fs/hydrafs/hfsd/mount";

#use constant PROC_MOUNT_DIR      =>"/export/proc";
use constant PROC_HFSD_INFO_FILE => "/proc/fs/hydrafs/hfsd/info";
use constant DEBUG               => 0;
use constant IGNORE_SERVICE      => 0;

#use constant MAX_HFS_PER_AN             =>250;
#use constant RETRY_COUNT                =>3;
use constant GET_ALL_HFS_TIMEOUT => 12;

#use constant HFS_COUNT_TO_CHANGE_AN =>250;

use constant CREATING_TIME => 600;

#our $bar=4;

sub new {
    my $class = shift;

    my $this  = {};
    bless $this, $class;

    return $this;
}

sub getname {

    my $this = shift;

    print "Ankur";
}

1;
```

#### hfs.pl

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

#
use strict;
use warnings;

use hfs_const;

my $const = new hfs_const();
my $isRO  = 3;

if ( $isRO != 4 ) {
    print $hfs_const::bar;
    print hfs_const::RETRY_COUNT;
    print $const->HFS_COUNT_TO_CHANGE_AN;
    print hfs_const::MAX_HFS_PER_AN;
}
else {
    print hfs_const::GET_ALL_HFS_TIMEOUT;
}

$const->getname();
```

I get the following warning on compilation

```
int@mint-VirtualBox ~ $ perl -c hfs.pl
Name "hfs_const::RETRY_COUNT" used only once: possible typo at hfs.pl line 12.
Name "hfs_const::MAX_HFS_PER_AN" used only once: possible typo at hfs.pl line 14.
Name "hfs_const::bar" used only once: possible typo at hfs.pl line 11.
hfs.pl syntax OK
```

But I do not receive any warning for constant HFS_COUNT_TO_CHANGE_AN which is used through object.

Can anybody explain why is it happening?

Comment: Also i have modules which are using constant in the object method way and when we compile it doesn't throw any warning as supposed. Is there any other way using objects only by which we can get the warning in case the constant is not defined in module.

Comment: Please add some layout to your code in the form of indentation and blank lines. It is much more difficult to read your code and spot errors without it.

Comment: This generates `Can't locate object method "HFS_COUNT_TO_CHANGE_AN" via package "hfs_const"`

Comment: Note that your module files and corresponding package names should begin with a capital letter. You should have `package HfsConst` in file `HfsConst.pm`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're treating `HFS_COUNT_TO_CHANGE_AN` as a method (`$const->HFS_COUNT_TO_CHANGE_AN`) so Perl won't check that it exists at compile time. You'll get a run-time error though.

Comment: Thanks, hence during compilation perl only checks the syntax and lexical scope of variables. It doesn't check method prototype and it wouldn't check constant variable as it treats it as method.

Comment: Note that perl *cannot* check this at compile time, because `$const` has no value until run time and there is nothing to check beforehand